# Select2 div overflow

Tags: css, jquery-select2

I have a table at the bottom of my page with rows of select2 dropdowns.

Unless I pad the bottom the select2 won't trigger.  Even then I need to adust my CSS to eliminate the wrapper div `overflow-y: auto;`

Before (with `overflow-y: auto;`):

[image]

After (cleared `overflow-y: auto;`)

[image]

Any initial thoughts on where to start looking to adjust the CSS on this or perhaps a Select2 option?  Ideally the wrapper div would just expand as required for the select and avoid the excess padding.

**UPDATE**

I looked again - it seems like I may have been mistaken.  It looks like the select2 is in fact trying to display upwards when at the bottom of the screen.  Working a codepen to reproduce this.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share that replicates the issue?

Comment: I am working on that - having trouble getting a codepen to accurately reproduce the issue.  Updating the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Took some head banging but sorted it out.  I have these selects originally in a modal.  I had to add this to make that work:

```
dropdownParent: $(this).parent()
```

This was the issue all along ‍♂️